# Timer trigger Azure function - How to get datetime details of the last successful execution?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

What is the difference between `TimeInfo.ScheduleStatus.Last` vs `TimeInfo.ScheduleStatus.LastUpdated`?

What want to know is the datetime details of **last** **successful** run of my timer trigger Azure function? not just when it was last run regardless of outcome (success or failure).

Answer (score 1):

> What is the difference between TimeInfo.ScheduleStatus.Last vs
> TimeInfo.ScheduleStatus.LastUpdated?

To know this, you can go to the github to have a look of the comment of the source code:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/a3a5a49a64f3592c1eb7c1296086dc83c2011e96/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Scheduling/ScheduleStatus.cs#L16

and this source code of azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions/Extensions/Timers/Listener/TimerListener.cs#L97

> Gets or sets the last recorded schedule occurrence

So the 'Last' means the time you last trigger the function, no matter success or failure.

And

```
    ScheduleStatus = new ScheduleStatus
    {
        Last = adjustedInvocationTime,
        Next = _schedule.GetNextOccurrence(adjustedInvocationTime),
        LastUpdated = adjustedInvocationTime
    };
```

You can find the 'Last' and 'LastUpdated' is get from the same value.

If you want to get the success time of last success with build-in value, then there is no way. You can use 'FunctionResult' to return whether the function is success. If you success trigger the function, then return `FunctionResult(true)`.:)

Comment: @ Bowman Zhu, What is 'FunctionResult'? How it is useful in timer triggered Azure functions?